# How to create as many buttons as the number added within an edittext field?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I write a code whereby a user enters the number of buttons needed on a text field, these buttons then displays dynamically based on the number entered on the edit text field. Thanks

Comment: Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first .

Answer (score 1):

Read the count from the edit text and add the buttons like this inside a loop

```
Button button = new Button(this);
parent.addView(button);
```

Comment: Thanks @Saran Sankaran. can you please tell me how to read a count in edittext field, am quit new in Android development. thanks

Comment: I surely can tell you that, but that would just be spoon feeding. However, what I can tell you is, first you will have to get the instance of the `EditText` using `findViewById()` and use that instance to read the text from the `EditText`. I am sure you will be able to find out your solution from this.

Answer (score -1):

Should be fairly simple to do this. Just add these attributes to your XML first.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.nero.myapplication.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Number of Buttons"
    android:inputType="number"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

In your Edittext, make sure you have inputType to number so you can always expect to receive a whole number instead of string or anything else. I've also added a submit button which will listen to your request but you can change that however you like to trigger the function. Also you will need another layout/view where you will be displaying your buttons.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText main;
Button submit;
LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int noOfButtons = Integer.parseInt(main.getText().toString());

            for(int i = 0; i < noOfButtons; i++){
                Button button = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                layout.addView(button);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now you basically wire in all of your elements with your main activity class. Please note that I am using the old android studio version and that's why I have to declare the variable type (Button, Edittext, Layout) when I am wiring it in.
So you will simply create a onClickListener for your submit button which will then action the number of buttons the user has requested. It will then take the number in a loop and create a new button as needed.
Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nero for taking your time to answer this question it was spot_on